# Classlist add not working, link is not disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i need a link to appear when i click on another link and the clicked link needs to disappear i do this through class list by adding css class to display none but it doesn't
work i dont know why im not a master to js so please forgive me if any stupid mistakes are their

JS:

```
var link =   document.querySelector('a');
var lang = document.querySelector('lang');
var content = document.querySelector('.content')


link.forEach( el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {

        lang.querySelector('.active').classList.add('active');
        el.classList.remove('active');
    });
});
var data = {
    "english":{
        "hi" : "welcome",
        "Lang":"EN"
    },
    "arabic":{
        "hi" : "منزل",
        "Lang":"AR"
    }
}
```

here's the HTML that matters
HTML:

````
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav-logo.png" alt="Logo" height="70px"></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="lang active" id="eng"><a href="#" class="lang-link" language="english">EN</a></li>
        <li class="lang" id="ar"><a href="#" class="lang-link" language="arabic">AR</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav> ```
And css:
````

nav ul .active{

```js
    var link =   document.querySelector('a');
    var lang = document.querySelector('lang');
    var content = document.querySelector('.content')


    link.forEach( el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {

            lang.querySelector('.active').classList.add('active');
            el.classList.remove('active');
        });
    });
    var data = {
        "english":{
            "hi" : "welcome",
            "Lang":"EN"
        },
        "arabic":{
            "hi" : "منزل",
            "Lang":"AR"
        }
    }
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.navbar .logo {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  animation: slide-logo 2.2s;
}
@keyframes slide-logo {
  from {
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.navbar .logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.nav-items {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
}
.nav-items li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: black;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.nav-items li {
  display: block;
  animation: slide 2s;
}
@keyframes slide {
  from {
    margin-right: 60px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.nav-items li a:hover {
  background-color: #ffc9d2;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-items span {
  background-color: black;
  height: 42px;
  width: 4px;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='260' height='260' viewBox='0 0 260 260'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%23d1d1d1' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath d='M24.37 16c.2.65.39 1.32.54 2H21.17l1.17 2.34.45.9-.24.11V28a5 5 0 0 1-2.23 8.94l-.02.06a8 8 0 0 1-7.75 6h-20a8 8 0 0 1-7.74-6l-.02-.06A5 5 0 0 1-17.45 28v-6.76l-.79-1.58-.44-.9.9-.44.63-.32H-20a23.01 23.01 0 0 1 44.37-2zm-36.82 2a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-3.1 1.56.89 1.79 1.31-.66a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .86.02l2.88-1.27a3 3 0 0 1 2.43 0l2.88 1.27a1 1 0 0 0 .85-.02l3.1-1.55-.89-1.79-1.42.71a3 3 0 0 1-2.56.06l-2.77-1.23a1 1 0 0 0-.4-.09h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.4.09l-2.78 1.23a3 3 0 0 1-2.56-.06l-2.3-1.15a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1L.9 19.22a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01zm0-2h-4.9a21.01 21.01 0 0 1 39.61 0h-2.09l-.06-.13-.26.13h-32.31zm30.35 7.68l1.36-.68h1.3v2h-36v-1.15l.34-.17 1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0L2.26 23h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.56.06l1.67-.74h3.23l1.67.74a3 3 0 0 0 2.56-.06zM-13.82 27l16.37 4.91L18.93 27h-32.75zm-.63 2h.34l16.66 5 16.67-5h.33a3 3 0 1 1 0 6h-34a3 3 0 1 1 0-6zm1.35 8a6 6 0 0 0 5.65 4h20a6 6 0 0 0 5.66-4H-13.1z'/%3E%3Cpath id='path6_fill-copy' d='M284.37 16c.2.65.39 1.32.54 2H281.17l1.17 2.34.45.9-.24.11V28a5 5 0 0 1-2.23 8.94l-.02.06a8 8 0 0 1-7.75 6h-20a8 8 0 0 1-7.74-6l-.02-.06a5 5 0 0 1-2.24-8.94v-6.76l-.79-1.58-.44-.9.9-.44.63-.32H240a23.01 23.01 0 0 1 44.37-2zm-36.82 2a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-3.1 1.56.89 1.79 1.31-.66a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .86.02l2.88-1.27a3 3 0 0 1 2.43 0l2.88 1.27a1 1 0 0 0 .85-.02l3.1-1.55-.89-1.79-1.42.71a3 3 0 0 1-2.56.06l-2.77-1.23a1 1 0 0 0-.4-.09h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.4.09l-2.78 1.23a3 3 0 0 1-2.56-.06l-2.3-1.15a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01zm0-2h-4.9a21.01 21.01 0 0 1 39.61 0h-2.09l-.06-.13-.26.13h-32.31zm30.35 7.68l1.36-.68h1.3v2h-36v-1.15l.34-.17 1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.56.06l1.67-.74h3.23l1.67.74a3 3 0 0 0 2.56-.06zM246.18 27l16.37 4.91L278.93 27h-32.75zm-.63 2h.34l16.66 5 16.67-5h.33a3 3 0 1 1 0 6h-34a3 3 0 1 1 0-6zm1.35 8a6 6 0 0 0 5.65 4h20a6 6 0 0 0 5.66-4H246.9z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M159.5 21.02A9 9 0 0 0 151 15h-42a9 9 0 0 0-8.5 6.02 6 6 0 0 0 .02 11.96A8.99 8.99 0 0 0 109 45h42a9 9 0 0 0 8.48-12.02 6 6 0 0 0 .02-11.96zM151 17h-42a7 7 0 0 0-6.33 4h54.66a7 7 0 0 0-6.33-4zm-9.34 26a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-4.34a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-4.34a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-7a7 7 0 1 1 0-14h42a7 7 0 1 1 0 14h-9.34zM109 27a9 9 0 0 0-7.48 4H101a4 4 0 1 1 0-8h58a4 4 0 0 1 0 8h-.52a9 9 0 0 0-7.48-4h-42z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M39 115a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm6-8a6 6 0 1 1-12 0 6 6 0 0 1 12 0zm-3-29v-2h8v-6H40a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v10H22l-1.33 4-.67 2h2.19L26 130h26l3.81-40H58l-.67-2L56 84H42v-6zm-4-4v10h2V74h8v-2h-8a2 2 0 0 0-2 2zm2 12h14.56l.67 2H22.77l.67-2H40zm13.8 4H24.2l3.62 38h22.36l3.62-38z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M129 92h-6v4h-6v4h-6v14h-3l.24 2 3.76 32h36l3.76-32 .24-2h-3v-14h-6v-4h-6v-4h-8zm18 22v-12h-4v4h3v8h1zm-3 0v-6h-4v6h4zm-6 6v-16h-4v19.17c1.6-.7 2.97-1.8 4-3.17zm-6 3.8V100h-4v23.8a10.04 10.04 0 0 0 4 0zm-6-.63V104h-4v16a10.04 10.04 0 0 0 4 3.17zm-6-9.17v-6h-4v6h4zm-6 0v-8h3v-4h-4v12h1zm27-12v-4h-4v4h3v4h1v-4zm-6 0v-8h-4v4h3v4h1zm-6-4v-4h-4v8h1v-4h3zm-6 4v-4h-4v8h1v-4h3zm7 24a12 12 0 0 0 11.83-10h7.92l-3.53 30h-32.44l-3.53-30h7.92A12 12 0 0 0 130 126z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M212 86v2h-4v-2h4zm4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-20 0v.1a5 5 0 0 0-.56 9.65l.06.25 1.12 4.48a2 2 0 0 0 1.94 1.52h.01l7.02 24.55a2 2 0 0 0 1.92 1.45h4.98a2 2 0 0 0 1.92-1.45l7.02-24.55a2 2 0 0 0 1.95-1.52L224.5 96l.06-.25a5 5 0 0 0-.56-9.65V86a14 14 0 0 0-28 0zm4 0h6v2h-9a3 3 0 1 0 0 6H223a3 3 0 1 0 0-6H220v-2h2a12 12 0 1 0-24 0h2zm-1.44 14l-1-4h24.88l-1 4h-22.88zm8.95 26l-6.86-24h18.7l-6.86 24h-4.98zM150 242a22 22 0 1 0 0-44 22 22 0 0 0 0 44zm24-22a24 24 0 1 1-48 0 24 24 0 0 1 48 0zm-28.38 17.73l2.04-.87a6 6 0 0 1 4.68 0l2.04.87a2 2 0 0 0 2.5-.82l1.14-1.9a6 6 0 0 1 3.79-2.75l2.15-.5a2 2 0 0 0 1.54-2.12l-.19-2.2a6 6 0 0 1 1.45-4.46l1.45-1.67a2 2 0 0 0 0-2.62l-1.45-1.67a6 6 0 0 1-1.45-4.46l.2-2.2a2 2 0 0 0-1.55-2.13l-2.15-.5a6 6 0 0 1-3.8-2.75l-1.13-1.9a2 2 0 0 0-2.5-.8l-2.04.86a6 6 0 0 1-4.68 0l-2.04-.87a2 2 0 0 0-2.5.82l-1.14 1.9a6 6 0 0 1-3.79 2.75l-2.15.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.54 2.12l.19 2.2a6 6 0 0 1-1.45 4.46l-1.45 1.67a2 2 0 0 0 0 2.62l1.45 1.67a6 6 0 0 1 1.45 4.46l-.2 2.2a2 2 0 0 0 1.55 2.13l2.15.5a6 6 0 0 1 3.8 2.75l1.13 1.9a2 2 0 0 0 2.5.8zm2.82.97a4 4 0 0 1 3.12 0l2.04.87a4 4 0 0 0 4.99-1.62l1.14-1.9a4 4 0 0 1 2.53-1.84l2.15-.5a4 4 0 0 0 3.09-4.24l-.2-2.2a4 4 0 0 1 .97-2.98l1.45-1.67a4 4 0 0 0 0-5.24l-1.45-1.67a4 4 0 0 1-.97-2.97l.2-2.2a4 4 0 0 0-3.09-4.25l-2.15-.5a4 4 0 0 1-2.53-1.84l-1.14-1.9a4 4 0 0 0-5-1.62l-2.03.87a4 4 0 0 1-3.12 0l-2.04-.87a4 4 0 0 0-4.99 1.62l-1.14 1.9a4 4 0 0 1-2.53 1.84l-2.15.5a4 4 0 0 0-3.09 4.24l.2 2.2a4 4 0 0 1-.97 2.98l-1.45 1.67a4 4 0 0 0 0 5.24l1.45 1.67a4 4 0 0 1 .97 2.97l-.2 2.2a4 4 0 0 0 3.09 4.25l2.15.5a4 4 0 0 1 2.53 1.84l1.14 1.9a4 4 0 0 0 5 1.62l2.03-.87zM152 207a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm6 2a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-11 1a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-6 0a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm3-5a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-8 8a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm3 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm0 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4 7a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm5-2a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm5 4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4-6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm6-4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-4-3a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4-3a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-5-4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-24 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm16 5a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm7-5a7 7 0 1 1-14 0 7 7 0 0 1 14 0zm86-29a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm19 9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-14 5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-25 1a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm5 4a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm9 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm15 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm12-2a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-11-14a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-19 0a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm6 5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-25 15c0-.47.01-.94.03-1.4a5 5 0 0 1-1.7-8 3.99 3.99 0 0 1 1.88-5.18 5 5 0 0 1 3.4-6.22 3 3 0 0 1 1.46-1.05 5 5 0 0 1 7.76-3.27A30.86 30.86 0 0 1 246 184c6.79 0 13.06 2.18 18.17 5.88a5 5 0 0 1 7.76 3.27 3 3 0 0 1 1.47 1.05 5 5 0 0 1 3.4 6.22 4 4 0 0 1 1.87 5.18 4.98 4.98 0 0 1-1.7 8c.02.46.03.93.03 1.4v1h-62v-1zm.83-7.17a30.9 30.9 0 0 0-.62 3.57 3 3 0 0 1-.61-4.2c.37.28.78.49 1.23.63zm1.49-4.61c-.36.87-.68 1.76-.96 2.68a2 2 0 0 1-.21-3.71c.33.4.73.75 1.17 1.03zm2.32-4.54c-.54.86-1.03 1.76-1.49 2.68a3 3 0 0 1-.07-4.67 3 3 0 0 0 1.56 1.99zm1.14-1.7c.35-.5.72-.98 1.1-1.46a1 1 0 1 0-1.1 1.45zm5.34-5.77c-1.03.86-2 1.79-2.9 2.77a3 3 0 0 0-1.11-.77 3 3 0 0 1 4-2zm42.66 2.77c-.9-.98-1.87-1.9-2.9-2.77a3 3 0 0 1 4.01 2 3 3 0 0 0-1.1.77zm1.34 1.54c.38.48.75.96 1.1 1.45a1 1 0 1 0-1.1-1.45zm3.73 5.84c-.46-.92-.95-1.82-1.5-2.68a3 3 0 0 0 1.57-1.99 3 3 0 0 1-.07 4.67zm1.8 4.53c-.29-.9-.6-1.8-.97-2.67.44-.28.84-.63 1.17-1.03a2 2 0 0 1-.2 3.7zm1.14 5.51c-.14-1.21-.35-2.4-.62-3.57.45-.14.86-.35 1.23-.63a2.99 2.99 0 0 1-.6 4.2zM275 214a29 29 0 0 0-57.97 0h57.96zM72.33 198.12c-.21-.32-.34-.7-.34-1.12v-12h-2v12a4.01 4.01 0 0 0 7.09 2.54c.57-.69.91-1.57.91-2.54v-12h-2v12a1.99 1.99 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-1.66-.88zM75 176c.38 0 .74-.04 1.1-.12a4 4 0 0 0 6.19 2.4A13.94 13.94 0 0 1 84 185v24a6 6 0 0 1-6 6h-3v9a5 5 0 1 1-10 0v-9h-3a6 6 0 0 1-6-6v-24a14 14 0 0 1 14-14 5 5 0 0 0 5 5zm-17 15v12a1.99 1.99 0 0 0 1.22 1.84 2 2 0 0 0 2.44-.72c.21-.32.34-.7.34-1.12v-12h2v12a3.98 3.98 0 0 1-5.35 3.77 3.98 3.98 0 0 1-.65-.3V209a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h16a4 4 0 0 0 4-4v-24c.01-1.53-.23-2.88-.72-4.17-.43.1-.87.16-1.28.17a6 6 0 0 1-5.2-3 7 7 0 0 1-6.47-4.88A12 12 0 0 0 58 185v6zm9 24v9a3 3 0 1 0 6 0v-9h-6z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M-17 191a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm19 9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-14 5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-25 1a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm5 4a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm9 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm15 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm12-2a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H4zm-11-14a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-19 0a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm6 5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-25 15c0-.47.01-.94.03-1.4a5 5 0 0 1-1.7-8 3.99 3.99 0 0 1 1.88-5.18 5 5 0 0 1 3.4-6.22 3 3 0 0 1 1.46-1.05 5 5 0 0 1 7.76-3.27A30.86 30.86 0 0 1-14 184c6.79 0 13.06 2.18 18.17 5.88a5 5 0 0 1 7.76 3.27 3 3 0 0 1 1.47 1.05 5 5 0 0 1 3.4 6.22 4 4 0 0 1 1.87 5.18 4.98 4.98 0 0 1-1.7 8c.02.46.03.93.03 1.4v1h-62v-1zm.83-7.17a30.9 30.9 0 0 0-.62 3.57 3 3 0 0 1-.61-4.2c.37.28.78.49 1.23.63zm1.49-4.61c-.36.87-.68 1.76-.96 2.68a2 2 0 0 1-.21-3.71c.33.4.73.75 1.17 1.03zm2.32-4.54c-.54.86-1.03 1.76-1.49 2.68a3 3 0 0 1-.07-4.67 3 3 0 0 0 1.56 1.99zm1.14-1.7c.35-.5.72-.98 1.1-1.46a1 1 0 1 0-1.1 1.45zm5.34-5.77c-1.03.86-2 1.79-2.9 2.77a3 3 0 0 0-1.11-.77 3 3 0 0 1 4-2zm42.66 2.77c-.9-.98-1.87-1.9-2.9-2.77a3 3 0 0 1 4.01 2 3 3 0 0 0-1.1.77zm1.34 1.54c.38.48.75.96 1.1 1.45a1 1 0 1 0-1.1-1.45zm3.73 5.84c-.46-.92-.95-1.82-1.5-2.68a3 3 0 0 0 1.57-1.99 3 3 0 0 1-.07 4.67zm1.8 4.53c-.29-.9-.6-1.8-.97-2.67.44-.28.84-.63 1.17-1.03a2 2 0 0 1-.2 3.7zm1.14 5.51c-.14-1.21-.35-2.4-.62-3.57.45-.14.86-.35 1.23-.63a2.99 2.99 0 0 1-.6 4.2zM15 214a29 29 0 0 0-57.97 0h57.96z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 100%;
  height: 505px;
}
.hero{
    background-image: url(../images/icecream.jpg) ;
    background-size: 100% 700px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
.hero h1{
    font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
}
.hero .brand-logo{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
}
.hero h1 span{
    color: #e11584;}
.hero .btn-1{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 18px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    color: white;
    font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
    background-color: #e11584;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
.hero .btn-1:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.hero a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.footer{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e11584;
  color: white;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul .active{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon_io/favicon.ico">
    <title>Veloce</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav-logo.png" alt="Logo" height="70px"></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="lang active" id="eng"><a href="#" class="lang-link" language="english">EN</a></li>
        <li class="lang" id="ar"><a href="#" class="lang-link" language="arabic">AR</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="brand-logo" alt="Veloce logo" height="400px" width="700px">
        <h1 class="content">Ice creams you <span>love</span></h1>
        <a href="#"><button class="btn-1"> Visit Menu</button></a>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>&copy; Veloce 2022</p>
      <p>Socials:</p>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/insta.png" alt="Instagram" height="20px" width="20px"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Twitter"></a>
    </footer>

  </body>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

}

Comment: Can you please try and render your code interactive by adding it in a code snippet? That would help reproducing your issue a lot.

Comment: `lang.querySelector('.active').classList.add('active');`
You're trying to select something that with classname "active" and add it again?

Comment: You confused me.

Comment: `link` is an element, you should see an error in the console (forEach is not a function).

Comment: Please try and read the documentation on the functions you are using. `querySelector` will not find your elements with 'lang', as it is a class. And there are other misuses that prohibit your code from working.

Comment: @ChangAlex changed it still not working

Comment: Here are a few pointers: first there is confusion between `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. The first one will return only the 1st element it finds, the second one will returns all elments wich match the selector. `querySelectorAll` is what you need. 2nd issue you're not targeting elements correctly. `querySelector('lang')` will return the `<lang>` element, what you need is `querySelectorAll('.lang')` (= all elements with the class lang).

Comment: 3rd in the event listerner callback you have the wrong logic. You should remove the `active` class from all element with it and add it on the link wich has been clicked on

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser's dev tools inspect facility? It would help you find several of the JS errors.